# Where to find the loss corresponding to the best configuration with hyperopt?

Tags: python, performance

I tuning an algorithm with "hyperopt" Python package,
I can't find how to print the loss of the best config:

```
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, rand, space_eval, Trials
trials = Trials()
best = fmin(ils, space, rand.suggest, 100, trials=trials)
print ...
```

I already know how to print the best config!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do that as follows:

```
fnvals = [t['result']['loss'] for t in trials.trials]
print max(fnvals)
```

Maybe there is simple way?!

Answer (score 1):

```
print trials.best_trial['result']['loss']
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
print min(trials.losses())
```

Or `max()` in your case

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Hyperopt documentation](https://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/getting-started/minimizing_functions/):

> trials.losses() - a list of losses (float for each 'ok' trial)

So, we can do:

```
min(trials.losses())
```

**min** because hyperopt minimizes the score we are trying to optimize.